# Local HTTP redirects in the browser

Tags: http, firefox, browser, redirect

I want to hack my browser to redirect from one website to another when I type in a URL.

For example:

When I type "facebook.com" into my Firefox address bar, I want it to redirect to "lite.facebook.com"

Are there configuration files in Firefox that allow me to do this? Almost like a local mod_rewrite?

Comment: I'm afraid to ask why you're thinking about doing something like this. Do explain, we might give you better suggestions.

Comment: Regular facebook.com is just way too bulky for me. I need something fresh like lite.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) [plugin for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) will let you do this.

For instance, it will let you redirect a page to the equivalent secure version, like so:

[`window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/^http:/, 'https:');`](http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/patterns/redirect.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing more than just changing hosts, and you're using Firefox, you might consider [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/).  It might be a little more than what you're looking for, though.

Answer (score 0):

Write a [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) script that does the redirect in javascript.